# What causes the "brown-background" issue when using MonoTouch and MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

We use MonoTouch for our application and we sometime experience (after some usage) that the view controller background suddenly turns brown. This happens when we pop another view controller from the navigation controller. We're using MonoTouch.Dialog for everything. What causes this problem and what's the solution?

Example can be seen here:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually due to a bug in our own code.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, it has to do with the cell being re-cycled, you must set all the attributes of the cell, otherwise you might end up using one from before.  I'm talking about background, foreground, colors, etc.

Comment: See: http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't affect the cells, but the background.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some examples of your code usage?

Do you explicitly set the View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White on view instantiation or when you're popping a view off the Navstack?